# That contains VS containing

Tags: grammar, writing

what is the difference between:

> "How to create a file **that contains** a list of names"

and

> "How to create a file **containing** a list of names"

And what is the type of the word "containing" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Containing*" is the present participle of the verb "*to contain*", so this means the item is already in its container.

For example:

> I have a jug that contains 2 litres of water.

This means your jug is *capable* of containing 2 litres.

> I have a jug containing 2 litres of water.

This means your jug has 2 litres of water in it.

If your instructions include the steps of actually putting names into the file, then you could say "*this is how to create a file containing a list of names*" because you will actually create a file with names in it. However, if the instructions just cover creating the file which is capable of holding names, then use "..that contains" (or even "*to contain*"), because that is its purpose.

Comment: In the last line, did you mean "..to contain" as you have written it, or "..that contains" instead?

Comment: @XY Either would work.